# Debezium with MongoDB - Produced record's payload contains backslash

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm implementing data extract using the debezium mongodb connector, building up upon the official documentation: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mongodb.html

Everything is working quite fine - except that the payload contains backslash as you can see in the `after` attribute. Well, oddly enough, the attribute `source` is right.

```
{
  "after": "{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"63626d5993801d8fd1140993\"},\"document\": \"29973569000204\",\"document_type\": \"CNPJ\"}",
  "patch": null,
  "filter": null,
  "source": {
    "version": "1.7.1.Final",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "ts_ms": 8466513,
    "snapshot": "false",
    "db": "database",
    "sequence": null,
    "rs": "atlas-iurhise-shard-0",
    "collection": "mongo_collection",
    "ord": 1,
    "h": null,
    "tord": 4,
    "stxnid": "281f4230-d8cc-3d23-a556-89923b45e25f:168"
  },
  "op": "c",
  "ts_ms": 1667394905422,
  "transaction": null
}
```

I tried this solution, but it doesn't work for me: [Debezium Outbox Pattern property transforms.outbox.table.expand.json.payload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70323167/debezium-outbox-pattern-property-transforms-outbox-table-expand-json-payload-not)

these are my settings:

```
{
  "name": "DebeziumDataExtract",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "mongodb.hosts": "removed",
    "mongodb.name": "removed",
    "mongodb.user": "removed",
    "mongodb.password": "removed",
    "mongodb.ssl.enabled": "true",
    "collection.whitelist": "removed",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "hstore.handling.mode": "json",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": "1000",
    "heartbeat.topics.prefix": "removed",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 3,  
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": 1,  
    "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "compact",  
    "topic.creation.default.compression.type": "lz4",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.collection.expand.json.payload": "true"
  }
}
```

and waiting for a payload like this:

```
{
  "after": {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63626d5993801d8fd1140993"
    },
    "document": "29973585214796",
    "document_type": "CNPJ"
  },
  "patch": null,
  "filter": null,
  "source": {
    "version": "1.7.1.Final",
    "connector": "mongodb",
    "name": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "ts_ms": 8466513,
    "snapshot": "false",
    "db": "database",
    "sequence": null,
    "rs": "atlas-iurhise-shard-0",
    "collection": "mongo_collection",
    "ord": 1,
    "h": null,
    "tord": 4,
    "stxnid": "281f4230-d8cc-3d23-a556-89923b45e25f:168"
  },
  "op": "c",
  "ts_ms": 1667394905422,
  "transaction": null
}
```

Could someone help me?

########## UPDATES ##########

After @onecricketeer comments I tried this:

```
{
  "name": "DebeziumTransportPlanner",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "tasks.max": "3",
    "mongodb.hosts": "stg-transport-planner-0-shard-00-00-00.xmapa.mongodb.net,stg-transport-planner-0-shard-00-01.xmapa.mongodb.net,stg-transport-planner-0-shard-00-02.xmapa.mongodb.net",
    "mongodb.name": "stg-transport-planner-01",
    "mongodb.user": "oploguser-stg",
    "mongodb.password": "vCh1NtV4PoY8PeSJ",
    "mongodb.ssl.enabled": "true",
    "collection.whitelist": "stg-transport-planner-01[.]aggregated_transfers",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "hstore.handling.mode": "json",
    "decimal.handling.mode": "string",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": "1000",
    "heartbeat.topics.prefix": "__debeziumtransport-planner-heartbeat",
    "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 3,  
    "topic.creation.default.partitions": 1,  
    "topic.creation.default.cleanup.policy": "compact",  
    "topic.creation.default.compression.type": "lz4",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.ExtractNewDocumentState",
    "transforms.unwrap.collection.expand.json.payload": "true",
    "transforms.unwrap.collection.fields.additional.placement": "route_external_id:header,transfer_index:header"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `JsonConverter` instead of `StringConverter` if you want the data to be a *JSON object* rather than a String.

Also, you are missing `transforms.unwrap.type`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the same result.

Could it be something related to the MongoDB version?
db.version() = "4.4.17"

Comment: I don't think the database matters since it's a serialization problem. 1) your key and value converter are set to different classes... `connect.storage` package is not correct...  2) Try setting `"value.converter.schemas.enable"` to true since it'll still be a string (as JSON) if that is false

Comment: Now this is partially working, but it's a step forward. 

After I changed it to `value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` the message sent to Kafka contains only the value contained in the `after` attribute but without the backslash
`
{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "63626d5993801d8fd1140993"
    },
    "document": "29973585214796",
    "document_type": "CNPJ"
  }
`
The other attributes, which are important, have disappeared, like: `op` and `source`

Comment: Probably it will work `transforms.unwrap.add.fields=op,table,lsn,source.ts_ms` ... I'll try it and let us know.

Thank for your help

Comment: What does transforms.unwrap.type do?

Comment: @Kay it sets a class for the transform named unwrap. Look at the class in the question. Look at the Debezium documentation for what the class does

Comment: ah okay thanks, i was unsure what that was doing. As i am looking for something that parses the datatypes automatically. e.g removing the $oid, $dates etc